# mapbox gl expression to match multiple values

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

i have a layer that i want to filter by multiple values stored in array

```
let filter = ['in','id', 1,2,3]
map.setFilter('layer_name',filter)
```

this works fine and it will return only features with ID 1,2,3
but in Mapbox GL specs, they label this `in` expression as deprecated
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-filter
and encourage using the new expressions, i think the expression `match` would work but don't know know it should look like, i tried to do like

```
['match', 'get', 'id', 1,2,3 ];
```

it's not really that clear in the Docs so if anyone can clarify it please

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the `match` expression works, it should look like:

```
let filter = ['match', ['get', 'id'], [1, 2, 3], true, false]
map.setFilter('layer_name',filter)
```

**Update:**

Since Mapbox GL JS [v1.6.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases/tag/v1.6.0), there's an `in` expression. It can check if a value is in an array:

```
['in', ['get', 'id'], ['literal', [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: thank you it works fine, but can you explain a bit what is the true , false for ?!
i understand what the rest is for

Comment: true/false are the output values, from the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-match): "Selects the output whose label value matches the input value, or the fallback value if no match is found." `false` is the fallback value in this case.

Comment: so in other words the filter would be " get the id field and match it for those [1,2,3] then if true return the feature matched, otherwise don't "
thanks, i think i got my head around it

Comment: it's more "get the id field, if it matches a value of [1,2,3] return true, otherwise false"

Comment: Great it works perfectly for me.